# There are three grids, and after clicking on the Grid3 control, then how to get the control values for Grid1 and Grid2. Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using Grid and trying to make control dynamically in loop.

There are 3 Grids, and after clicking on the Grid3 control, I would like to get the control values of Grid1 and Grid2.

Please see image.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

code behind:

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> myDictionary3 = _Model.getRoomStatusData(_Model.RoomTypesSel, _Model.StartTimeNames);
//Grid 1 x:Name="timelist"
for (int i = 0; i < _Model.StartTimeNames.Length; i++)
{   
    Label time = new Label() { Text = _Model.StartTimeNames[i], WidthRequest = 80 };               
    timelist.Children.Add(time, i, 0);               
}

//Grid 2 x:Name="roomtype"
for (int i = 0; i < roomtypes.Length; i++)
{
    roomtype.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());           
    Label room = new Label() { Text = _Model.RoomTypesSel[i].Name, WidthRequest = 80 };      
    roomtype.Children.Add(room, 0, i);
}


List<string[]> roomstatu = new List<string[]>()
{
    new string[] {"1","2","3","4","5","6"}, new string[] {"1","2","3","4","5","6"},new string[] {"1","2","3","4","5","6"},new string[] {"1","2","3","4","5","6"},new string[] {"1","2","3","4","5","6"},new string[] {"1","2","3","4","5","6"},new string[] {"1","2","3","4","5","6"},new string[] {"1","2","3","4","5","6"}
};
//Grid 3 x:Name="status"
int index = 0;
foreach (var item in roomstatu)
{
    status.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
    for (int i = 0; i < item.Length; i++)
    {
        status.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
        Label statuslabel = new Label() { Text = item[i], WidthRequest = 80};                           
        status.Children.Add(statuslabel, i, index);
    }
    index++;              
}
```

Comment: When they click.on a cell can you get the row/col that they clicked on?

Comment: Still not! but wait I'm trying. @Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, you can get the index of the label user tapped in the status grid. And then you can get the label's row position and column position by the index.

I have done a sample and it worked well, you can try the following code:

```
        int index = 0;
        foreach (var item in roomstatu)
        {
            status.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition());
            for (int i = 0; i < item.Length; i++)
            {
                status.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
                Label statuslabel = new Label() { Text = item[i], WidthRequest = 80 };
                status.Children.Add(statuslabel, i, index);
                statuslabel.GestureRecognizers.Add((new TapGestureRecognizer
                {
                    Command = new Command(async (obj) =>
                    {
                        Label temp = obj as Label;
                        Grid gridtemp = temp.Parent as Grid;
                        int position = gridtemp.Children.IndexOf(temp);
                        int columnindex = position % timelist.Children.Count;
                        int rowindex = (position / roomtype.Children.Count) +1;
                        
                        string timevalue = ((Label)timelist.Children[columnindex]).Text;
                        string roomtypealue = ((Label)roomtype.Children[rowindex]).Text;
                        temp.Text = timevalue + "+"+ roomtypealue;
                    }),
                    CommandParameter = statuslabel,
                }));
            }
            index++;
        }
```

Comment: How do I get the `IndexValue` of a `timevalue` inside `statuslabel.GestureRecognizers`? @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: What does the IndexValue mean? RowIndex or ColumnIndex? @Raj

Comment: Array index of timevalue @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: I'm doing like this and got it,  `int index = Array.IndexOf(_Model.StartTimeNames, timevalue);`  thank you @LiyunZhang-MSFT

Comment: All right, happy coding. @Raj